# Example of a finite Heyting algebra that is not Boolean

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, heyting-algebra

Simple question: what are some simple examples of a finite Heyting Algebras, that is not also a Boolean Algebra?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any finite chain with three or more elements will do.
Check the examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra#Examples).

By the way, it also follows from the last paragraph in the section [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra#Distributivity) in the same article, that every finite distributive lattice is a Heyting algebra.

Answer (score 10):

The lattice of open sets of any topological space is a Heyting algebra, which is very rarely a Boolean algebra (it is Boolean if and only if every open set is clopen).

The Heyting implication is defined by \begin{align*} U\rightarrow V &= \bigcup\{W\text{ open}\mid U \cap W \subseteq V\}\\ &= (U^c\cup V)^\circ,\end{align*}
where $X^c$ is the complement of $X$ and $Y^\circ$ is the interior of $Y$.

Stone's representation theorem for Heyting algebras (HAs) says that every HA is isomorphic to a sub-HA of the HA of open sets of some topological space.